# Accessing nested JSON data in React Component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Hi i am just starting to learn react as a side project.

Im using an express backend to call an api that returns some JSON to my component. I cant seem to access the nested array to iterate over and display.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../app.css';

export class Table extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        jsonItems: [],
        isLoaded: false
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.renderMyData();
}

renderMyData() {
    fetch('/api/nfl')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                jsonItems: JSON.parse(json),
                isLoaded: true
            })
        })
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.jsonItems.fullgameschedule);
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Test 1</th>
                    <th>Test 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
}
```

Json output:

```
{
"fullgameschedule": {
    "lastUpdatedOn": "2018-08-24 2:55:41 PM",
    "gameentry": [
     {
    "id": "43306",
    "week": "1",
    "scheduleStatus": "Normal",
    "originalDate": null,
    "originalTime": null,
    "delayedOrPostponedReason": null,
    "date": "2017-09-07",
    "time": "8:30PM",
    "awayTeam": {
      "ID": "73",
      "City": "Kansas City",
      "Name": "Chiefs",
      "Abbreviation": "KC"
    },
    "homeTeam": {
      "ID": "50",
      "City": "New England",
      "Name": "Patriots",
      "Abbreviation": "NE"
    },
    "location": "Gillette Stadium"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

jsonItems gets populated (as shown in my react dev tools). but i cant seem to iterate over the json array "gameentry"

I can print out {this.state.jsonItems.fullgameschedule} , but i cant access it any further for example {this.state.jsonItems.fullgameschedule.gameentry} or gameentry[0] without the error message:

> Cannot read property 'gameentry' of undefined

Which at first i thought was because of js being asynchronous that it was loading the component before it rendered, so i changed componentDidMount() to componentWillMount() and that should handle that. How can i access the array list and iterate over to display it to the component? or just a general point in the right direction.

EDIT: How im getting the data.

```
    var options = {
        url: url,
        auth: {
            user : 'xxx',
            password : 'xxx',
        }
    }
    app.get('/api/nfl', function (req, res) {
        request(options, function (err, response, body){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.send(JSON.stringify(response.body));
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As you thought since data is coming in an asynchronous way, you need to handle it somehow. When you try to get a property from an `undefined` object, you get an error like yours. So, you should use conditional rendering.

Before that, using `componentWillMount` instead of `componentDidMount` does not work since `render` does not wait for any of these two methods to finish its jobs. Actually, `componentWillMount` will be deprecated, so go with `componentDidMount` for the asynchronous operations.

Since you haven't shared the code how have you tried to get the data I'm giving a blind suggestion here.

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.jsonItems.fullgameschedule);
    return this.state.jsonItems.fullgameschedule && (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Test 1</th>
                    <th>Test 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{this.state.jsonItems.fullgameschedule.lastUpdatedOn}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

This is just an example. You can change it according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Okay cool , so i switched back to componentDidMount(). I tried the conditional statement, but it seems to gave me a new error of "Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing." which is pretty straightforward. I updated my question with the way i pull the data with the express route.

Comment: You are welcome. The error says enough as you said. But this time error is not related to how you fetched the data, you are not returning anything in the `render` method. Just update your question and add the whole render part.